# Get all Members for Groups

Tags: yammer

Below URL can give me all groups associated with me only.

```
https://www.yammer.com/api/v1/groups.json?mine=1
```

Also below URLs will give me all groups and user list..but how to find which user belongs to which group?

```
https://www.yammer.com/api/v1/groups.json?model_type=Group&page=3
https://www.yammer.com/api/v1/users.json?model_type=User&page=67
```

So can i get all members associated with group id?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The endpoint:

```
https://www.yammer.com/api/v1/users/in_group/[:Group_Id].json
```

will give you a list of users in a group

More info here:

https://developer.yammer.com/docs/usersin_groupidjson

Comment: Do you know if there is an upper limit to the number of users that this request supports?

Comment: The docs say 50, after that you have to pass in the page parameter to get more groups

Comment: I meant to get more users

Comment: To clarify the answer above, https://www.yammer.com/api/v1/users/in_group/[:Group_Id].json?page=1 would give you the first 50 and https://www.yammer.com/api/v1/users/in_group/[:Group_Id].json?page=2 would give you the second 50, etc etc.

Comment: is it possible to use top param for this request?